# On aodv networks in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to implement the network topology shown in the following code.
Each aodv node is connected to an extRouter, which can forward messages from external programs that are passed into the simulation to the corresponding aodv node.
The role of extRouter is only to connect to each aodv node and forward messages to them, without participating in the simulation of aodv networks.
The following error occurred when the simulation started:

[image]

```
package inet.examples.aodv.drone;   
import inet.common.scenario.ScenarioManager;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.ipv4.RoutingTableRecorder;
import inet.node.aodv.AodvRouter;
import inet.physicallayer.unitdisk.UnitDiskRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedVisualizer;
import inet.node.inet.Router;
import ned.DatarateChannel;
import inet.linklayer.contract.IPppInterface;

network Drone
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;
        @display("bgb=944.376,745.56");

    types:
          channel ethline extends DatarateChannel
        {
            datarate = 100 Gbps;
        }

    submodules:
        radioMedium: UnitDiskRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,200;is=s");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                config = xml("<config><interface hosts='*' address='145.236.x.x' netmask='255.255.0.0'/></config>");
                @display("p=100,100;is=s");
        }
        routingTableRecorder: RoutingTableRecorder {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,300;is=s");
        }
        visualizer: IntegratedVisualizer {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,30");
        }
        scenarioManager: ScenarioManager {
            parameters:
                script = default(xml("<scenario/>"));
                @display("p=100,400;is=s");
        }
        uav1: AodvRouter {
            parameters:
                @display("i=device/pocketpc_s;r=,,#707070");
                //ipv4.routingTable.routingFile = "cli1.mrt";
            gates:
                ethg[1];

        }
        uav2: AodvRouter {
            parameters:
                @display("i=device/pocketpc_s;r=,,#707070");
                ipv4.routingTable.routingFile = "cli2.mrt";
            gates:
                ethg[1];
        }
        uav3: AodvRouter {
            parameters:
                @display("i=device/pocketpc_s;r=,,#707070");
                ipv4.routingTable.routingFile = "cli3.mrt";
            gates:
                ethg[1];

        }
        uav4: AodvRouter {
            parameters:
                @display("i=device/pocketpc_s;r=,,#707070");
                ipv4.routingTable.routingFile = "cli4.mrt";
            gates:
                ethg[1];

        }
        extRouter: Router {
            parameters:

                @display("i=device/router_l;p=497.336,352.03");
            gates:
                ethg[4];

        }

    connections allowunconnected:

        extRouter.ethg[0] <--> ethline <-->uav1.ethg[0];
        extRouter.ethg[1] <--> ethline <--> uav2.ethg[0];
        extRouter.ethg[2] <--> ethline <--> uav3.ethg[0];
        extRouter.ethg[3] <--> ethline <--> uav4.ethg[0];
}
```

Comment: Here is the content of my cli1.mrt file. The rest of the files are the same                      
ifconfig:
# ethernet card (modelled by point-to-point link) 0 to router
name: eth0  inet_addr: 145.236.0.16   Mask: 255.255.0.0 MTU: 1500   Metric: 1  BROADCAST MULTICAST
ifconfigend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the XML config as follows:

```
 configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
        parameters:
            config = xml("<config><interface hosts='*' address='145.236.x.x' netmask='255.255.x.x'/></config>");
            @display("p=100,100;is=s");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This problem has been solved. "But I have encountered a new problem, so I have raised a new question. I hope to receive your help. Thank you very much."

Comment: Could you be so kind and mark the answer as accepted? It helps others to find a solution for similar problem in the future.